# Are probability measures weak-* closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

**Non-duplicates**

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157795/is-the-set-of-all-probability-measures-weak-closed) is in a different setting, and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277450/is-the-set-of-probability-measures-on-a-compact-metric-space-weak-closed) only deals with compact spaces which is the easy case.

Now for the question. Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. $\mathcal{C}_0(X)$ is the set of continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that go to zero at infinity, i.e. are less than any $\epsilon$ outside an appropriate compact set. One of the many Riesz representation theory gives an isometric isomorphism between $\mathcal{C}_0(X)$ and the space $M(X)$ of all complex regular Borel measures on $X$. So Banach-Alaoglu shows the ball of $M(X)$ is compact in the weak-* topology. Consider $P(X)\subseteq\{\mu:\|\mu\|\leq1\}$ the set of positive probability measures, i.e. $P(X)=\{\mu\in M(X):\mu\geq0,\mu(X)=1\}$.

> Is $P(X)$ weak-* compact?

$P(X)$ is contained in the ball, so if it is weak-* closed, it is closed in a compact set, hence compact. If $X$ is compact, certainly $f\equiv1$ is in $\mathcal{C}_0$, so if $\mu_\alpha$ is a net of probabilities converging to $\mu$, $1=\mu_n(X)=\mu_n(f)\to\mu(f)=\mu(X)$, and since limits preserve inequalities for any $g\geq0$ $\mu(g)\geq0$, so $\mu\in P(X)$.

The argument for positivity works in general. The hard part with noncompact spaces is $\mu(X)=1$. It is fairly easy to prove $\mu(X)\leq1$: one merely has to work with $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s in an appropriate way. But I couldn't find any way to conclude $\mu(X)\geq1$. Proceeding by contradiction with $\mu(X)=1-\delta$ doesn't lead me anywhere. I googled for 1-2 hours and found nothing: wherever the weak-* closure was mentioned, it was just assumed. So how do I prove this last bit? Is $\mu(X)\geq1$? Or are there cases where it isn't? And if so, counterexamples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say $X=\Bbb R$. Let $\mu_n=\delta_n$, a point mass at $n$. For $f\in C_0(\Bbb R)$ we have $$\int f\,d\mu_n=f(n)\to0\quad(n\to\infty).$$

---

**Comment:** Ian says something about "issues" like this. Of course one can get into trouble if one is not aware that this is how things are, but I submit that it's not a bug, it's a feature.

The example illustrates that $P(X)$ has a certain compactness when $X$ is compact that does not obtain when $X$ is just locally compact. This is as it "should" be. A probability measure is after all the distribution of a random variable. The family of, say, $[0,1]$-valued random variables "should" have some compactness not shared by the family of real-valued random variables! If $x_n$ is a random variable which equals $n$ with probability $1$ then we wouldn't *want* there to be a (real-valued!) random variable which was in any sense the limit of $x_n$.
Some day when we do want those random variables to have a limit we talk about $[-\infty,\infty]$-valued random variables instead.

The notion of a [tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures) family of measures should be mentioned here, in regard to the question of what the compact subsets of $P(\Bbb R)$ *are*.

Comment: Note that everything depends on what test functions you can use. For $C_c$ or $C_0$ you get issues like this one, but for $C_b$ this example does not go through.

Comment: @Ian Well of course. The question was about the dual of $C_0$. There's a reason for that - measures on $X$ form only an infinitesimal subset of the dual of $C_b$.

Comment: I agree that this is a feature, not a bug; at the same time, compactness is so convenient that in a sense non-compactness feels like pathology, because it forces us to deal with things more carefully.

Comment: @Ian In fact the word "issue" is neutral enough that I really didn't draw any conclusions about how you felt - you just got me thinking about the "issue" and I decided a few things should be said about it.

Comment: I guess this can be generalized to any noncompact space: with some choice one can construct a net $x_\alpha$ such that for all $\alpha\subseteq X$ compact one has $x_\alpha\notin\alpha$, then ordering the compacts by inclusion one concludes that $\delta_{x_\alpha}$ converges weak-* to zero since $f(x_\alpha)\to0$ for all $f\in C_0$, right? Btw is this possible without choice? And can we still conclude any probability is a limit of convex combinations of dirac Deltas somehow? In the compact case one uses Krein-Milman on the probabilities which are weak-* compact, but in noncompact spaces?

Comment: @MickG Yes, in any non-compact locally compact Hausdorff space there is a net $x_\alpha$ that tends to infinity, and then $\delta_{x_\alpha}\to0$. Does that need AC? Probably. Without AC one can still say simply that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\delta_x=0$, meaning [you can insert the definition here]. Seems to me that any probability measure is still a limit of convex combinations of delta functions: The dual of $C_0(X)$ is still the space of complex measures, an extreme point of the unit ball must be supported at a single point, etc. I don't see how compactness of the probabilities matters there.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich to conclude $P(X)=\overline{\operatorname{co}}(\operatorname{Ext}(P(X)))$, i.e. that the probabilities are the closed convex hull of their extremal points, I would need to use Krein-Milman and hence prove $P(X)$ is compact. But perhaps I can work on the whole ball $B_{M(X)}=B_{C_0^\ast}$ instead of just $P(X)$. So I would prove $P(X)\subseteq B_{C_0^\ast}=\overline{\operatorname{co}}(\operatorname{Ext}(B_{C_0^\ast}))$. But then I would need to show that the ball has no extremal points that are not positive probabilities.

Comment: @MickG Let's say a sub-probability measure is a $\mu\ge0$ with $\mu(X)\le 1$. Say a sub-convex combination of $x_j$ is $\sum t_jx_j$, where $t_j\ge0$ and $\sum t_j\le 1$. Say $X$ is locally compact hausdorff and let $K$ be the set of sub-probability measures. Then $K$ is convex and weak* compact. The extreme points of $K$ are the delta functions and $0$. So a convex combination of the extreme points of $K$ is the same as a sub-convex combination of delta functions. Now if $\mu$ is a probability measure there exists a net $\mu_\alpha$ of sub-convex combinations of delta functions[...]

Comment: @MickG [...] with $\mu_\alpha\to\mu$. It follows quite easily that $\mu_\alpha(X)\to1$. So $\mu_\alpha/\mu_\alpha(X)$ is a net of convex combinations of delta functions converging to $\mu$. (Detail: There exists $f\in C_0$ with $0\le f\le 1$ and $\int f\,d\mu>1-\epsilon$; hence $\mu_\alpha(X)\ge\int f\,d\mu_\alpha>1-\epsilon$ for "large enough" $\alpha$.)

Comment: So we need tp know positive measures are weak-* closed and the ball is weak-* compact and both are convex. And then we need that $K$, which is now weak-* compact and convex, has those extreme points. But any extreme point will be a positive measure which only takes values 0,1 and those are always deltas or the zero measure. Just to get all details written :). Finally let me think of how we prove $\mu_\alpha(X)\to1$.

Comment: See the "detail" at the end of my last comment. (This is actually a general fact about the weak* topology: If $x_\alpha^*\to x^*$ weak* then $\liminf ||x_\alpha^*||\ge||x^*||$.)

Comment: Yep, I meant precisely "let me assimilate your hint", and everything is clear. Thx.